# How to preserve > instead of &gt; in scala?

Tags: xml, scala

I am trying to create XML as `<formula>a > b</formula>` but when I do that `>` is converted into `&gt;`

```
scala> <formula>a > b</formula>
res0: scala.xml.Elem = <formula>a &gt; b</formula>

scala>
```

I need to preserve the `>`, how can I do that?

Comment: If you need to preserve the `>` then you are doing something wrong. So please explain why you think you need to preserve it.

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to. `<formula>a > b</formula>` is not valid XML, and if you tried to parse it back as XML, it would fail. Characters like `>` must be escaped because they are used to denote tags themselves. You can still access the text programmatically, and it will be un-escaped for you:

```
scala> <formula>"a > b"</formula>
res4: scala.xml.Elem = <formula>&quot;a &gt; b&quot;</formula>

scala> res4.text
res5: String = "a > b"
```

Comment: No, that's not true. It is not necessary to quote `>` as `&gt;` except when it appears as part of the sequence `]]>`. However, serializers often escape it unconditionally because that's easier than checking the surrounding characters. And it's fine to do so, because no consuming application should care whether the character is written as `>` or as `&gt;`.